# What is the clang equvivalent this declaration of a function pointer with __stdcall?

Tags: c++, c, windows, clang, clang++

I have the following declaration of a function pointer:

```
extern long (__stdcall *FooPtr)(int* i);
```

That is, a function pointer that points to a function to be called with the stdcall calling convention (in VS terms).

How can I translate this declaration so that clang understands it?

Comment: `__attribute__((stdcall))` maybe?

Comment: Did you try Googling `clang stdcall`? The answer is right there on the results page, you don't even need to click any of the results.

Comment: I also saw that but because of the title it doesn't completely seem a duplicate. Should we do something about it?

Comment: Yes @Mehrdad, I did try googling that. I specifically asked for the syntax in function pointers. Where do I need to place it in the function pointer declaration? All that turned up was bug reports of certain variations of the syntax. Again, I'm not asking about the stdcall attribute but its use in function pointer declarations.

Comment: @TamásSzelei: All you have to do is put `__attribute__((stdcall))` before the declaration (my version of Clang doesn't complain when you do). Did you try that? What error did you get?

Comment: @Mehrdad You can add that as an answer.

Comment: @Mehrdad I did not ask how to use `__attribute__`. For the future, try being less condescending and try to understand the actual question. There is no example of the usage of calling conventions on a function pointer declaration in the linked page. Nothing hints where the attribute should be applied in the case of a function pointer declaration. Just because it's obvious to you doesn't mean it should be obvious to everyone. Your behavior is what's wrong with StackOverflow these days.

Comment: @TamásSzelei: MarcoA told you *what* attribute to use, and he linked to a page that explained *how* to use *any* attribute. There's nothing different about calling conventions or function pointers here -- the same syntax works the same for all attributes, like I showed you. You simply didn't try it. All I'm asking is that in the future, you try the most obvious thing that's in front of you, that's all. I think that's helpful, not condescending. Come back tomorrow and re-read my comments, and if you genuinely still find them condescending, reply to me and I'll upvote your question.

Comment: @TamásSzelei: (And believe me, I *have* had my own share of condescending conversations before. This was certainly *not* intended to be one of them, and looking back, I honestly still don't think it was.)

Answer (score 4):

```
__attribute__((stdcall))
```

is the right answer: clang supports [the following list of attributes](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html) which, in syntax, are very similar to gcc's ones.

e.g.

```
#if defined(__clang__) || defined(__GNUC__)
   #define stdCallConv __attribute__ ((stdcall))
#else
   ...
```